# How to use middleware for custom UserProvider in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, ldap, laravel-middleware

I'm new to Laravel (5.5) and want to create an application with a custom authentication mechanism:

- If the user is not logged in, he/she should be redirected to /login.
- I want to use the session-guard.
- I have written and registered custom classes

  - `LdapUser extends Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser` and
  - `LdapUserProvider implements Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider`. Actually both are dummy implementations at the moment that return generic objects. Later, I want to check, if the user exists in my external ldap-directory and if the credentials are valid. Registration, internal user management or password reset are not intended. I just want to use the user's name and some properties in my blade templates.
- I modified `config/app.php` and `config/auth.php`, so that this provider can be used.

Now, I wonder how to proceed in order to actually use the authentication and access the `LdapUser` in my blade templates. I tried `{{ Auth::user()->name }}`, which led to this error message: *"Trying to get property of non-object."*

- How to I tell my app to check, if a valid session exists and otherwise redirect to the login page?
- How can I access the user's properties inside the blade templates?

This is my route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/helloworld', function () {return 'Hello World!';});
});
Route::get('/login', 'LdapLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('showLoginForm');
```

`/helloworld` now redirects to `/login` where I see the login-form, which is going to be handled by the `LdapLoginController`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LdapLoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
}
```

I would now expect that the session guard uses the `LdapUserProvider` to check the credentials:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\LdapUser;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;

class LdapUserProvider implements UserProvider
{
    public function retrieveById($id) 
    { 
        return $this->dummyUser();
    }

    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
        return $this->dummyUser();
    }

    public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
    {
        return new \Exception('not implemented');
    }

    public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token)
    {
        return new \Exception('not implemented');
    }

    protected function dummyUser()
    {
        $attributes = array(
          'id' => 123,
          'username' => 'chuckles',
          'password' => \Hash::make('SuperSecret'),
          'name' => 'Dummy User',
        );
        return new LdapUser($attributes);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, after submitting the login form, I'm always redirected back to `/login`, no matter what I enter :-(

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Auth::user()` gets currently logged in user. So if user is not logged in errors out. What you want to do is use middleware "guest".

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I updated my original post to give some more background. However: Is the middleware "guest" really what I should use? Or middleware "auth"?

Comment: `auth` is the one :), I came back to this question to edit my comment but could not.

Comment: ...or perhaps *web*? Isn‘t this the middlewareGroup for the session guard?